# The prefix "beans" for element "beans:beans" is not bound

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to add `CSS` and `JS` to `JSP` page in a `spring MVC` project so that I have included the reference of `js/css` folder in `dispatcher-servlet.xml` as below:

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">


    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.asurion" />

    <resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />
    <resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />

    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

    <beans:bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
        p:driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
        p:url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DataBaseName=test" p:username="test"
        p:password="test" />


    <beans:bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">com.asurion.dialect.SQlServerDBDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="reportDAO" class="com.asurion.dao.ReportDaoImpl"></beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="reportManager" class="com.asurion.service.ReportManagerImpl"></beans:bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

But it is showing "The prefix "beans" for element "beans:beans" is not bound" in spring configuration file itself so can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: Remove beans prefix for the root element

Comment: Replace `beans:beans` into `beans` should work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at your root element declaration - you've specified namespaces for the prefixes `mvc`, `xsi`, `context`, `p`, and `tx`, but nothing for `beans`. You've made `"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"` the default namespace, but you haven't given it an alias of `beans`.

The simplest fix here is probably just to do a search and replace to remove `beans:` from the whole file - just let the default to its job.

Alternatively, change this:

```
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
```

to

```
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
```

... and then check every element which doesn't have an explicit namespace prefix to see whether you *actually* mean it to be `beans`. For example, consider:

```
<resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />
```

If you're using explicit namespacing, that probably should be

```
<beans:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />
```

Although it sounds like it should *actually* be

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />
```

It's in the beans namespace by default at the moment, but the mixture of defaulting and using a `beans:` prefix is very confusing...

Comment: I removed <beans: from configuration file but now it is showing error for <resources tag:    cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'resources'. One of '{"http://
 www.springframework.org/schema/beans":import, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":alias, 
 "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, WC[##other:"http://www.springframework.org/
 schema/beans"], "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":beans}' is expected.

Comment: @tanajimane: Well that sounds like a different problem. Are you sure that isn't meant to be `mvc`?

Comment: God! I missed that...That answered my question.Thanks a lot