# Spring MVC and Maven (404 error: Resource )

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, maven-3

This my files which I think I configured correctly. My Tomcat 9 application is up and running correctly. I just don't know what it is the problem. Tomcat deploy the application but i'm not sure if the problem relays on Tomcat o Spring MVC

> rcontroller.java:

```
package com.mycompany.myspring;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class rcontroller {
    @ResponseBody
    public String getFoosBySimplePath() {
    return "Get some Foos";
}


    
}
```

> dispatch-servlet.xml:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="https://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="https://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc https://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        https://www.springframework.org/schema/context https://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.myspring" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean>
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

> web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="https://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="https://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee https://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>spring-mvc-example</display-name>

    <!-- Add Spring MVC DispatcherServlet as front controller -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/dispatch-servlet.xml</param-value>
            </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
 
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> 
    </servlet-mapping>
    
 </web-app>
```

> pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.myspring</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringMVC</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>SpringMVC</name>
    <description>Spring MVC Hello World Example</description>

    <!-- Add Spring Web and MVC dependencies -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName> <!-- added to remove Version from WAR file -->
    </build>
</project>
```

> Project structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. What is the exact problem ?

Anyway there are some problems on your `dispatch-servlet.xml`

1- the rows

```
 <beans:bean>
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
```

should be

```
 <beans:bean id="viewResolver" 
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
```

I.E. you should not close the tag bean before the class declaration and should assign it an id

2- I believe you may have some issues with the namespace `beans:` . If true the best think you could do is remove the `beans:` namespace prefix. Follow this answer

[The prefix "beans" for element "beans:beans" is not bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38656605/the-prefix-beans-for-element-beansbeans-is-not-bound)

3- contextConfigLocation should be `/WEB-INF/dispatch-servlet.xml`

```
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatch-servlet.xml</param-value>
```

4- In your controller you should map the method you want ot expose with @GetMapping or òRequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)

```
@GetMapping
@ResponseBody
public String getFoosBySimplePath() {
```

I suggest also not to map your controller to / but to some subpath

Comment: I apologize if the question its not clear. I did what you said but the problem remain I got `404.The required resource is not available.`   And when I clean and build I go a message at the bottom of the log `/home/educacion/NetBeansProjects/MYSPRING/target/SpringMVC/META-INF/context.xml (the file or directory does not exist)`

Comment: Hello, now i understand better. For the build problem, try the point 3 i added to my answer. For the 404 problem, it's normal: you return a string which is not a view name. You want to return just a string as response body ?

Comment: Yes, exactly I want to return just a String. But Im not sure where to put the `dispatch-servlet` as Maven put the `web.xml` on the `Other sources` carpet but Im not sure where to put `dispatch-servlet.xml`.

Comment: Also I edit the my question. I changed the image of the project structure. It shows the structure that Maven creates for a web application. In that project the `index.html` shows on the Browser. But I mapped the `@RequestMapping` seems to not be working when I hit the address on the Browser. I tried to change it to `/hello` but the problem remains.

Comment: How maven does build the folder structure under target ?

Comment: After the build it is as follows: `classes`,`endorsed`,`classes`, `generated-sources`,`classes`, `maven-archiver`, `maven-status`, `mavenproject1....SNAPSHOT..`,`test-classes`, and the jar.

Comment: You use spring-boot ? Anyway, under mavenproject1 there should be your app layout. Your web.xml and dispatch-servlet.xml should be under WEB-INF folder, with the config you put.

Comment: Instead in general, in your project the web.xml and dispatch-servlet.xml should be in a folder like WebContent. Maybe a more correct setting in pom.xml is ${basedir}/WebContent. But is web.xml working ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219060/discussion-between-tomas-and-massimo).

Answer (score 0):

in your folder structure, index.html file is located under the webapp folder. but in the dispatch-servlet.xml file, you set the path as a WEB-INF folder.

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".html" />
</beans:bean>
```

hence, move index.html file into WEB-INF folder

then, config the welcome file in the web.xml file as given below,

```
<display-name>spring-mvc-example</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: But if you see in `rcontroller.java` I return a String. I want to return that String instead of `index.html`

Comment: @TOMAS don't worry about welcome file configuration. above code simply return `Get some Foos`. pleas try with it

Comment: This is the error: `HTTP 404 Status - Not Found
Type Status report

message / SpringMVC

Description The required resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat / 9.0.24`